# AngularJS: How to remove current view url from window.history?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have `#/load-data` view with spinner. When data load is complete controller redirects to differen view `$location.path('/show-info/')`. 
How to remove #/load-data from history to avoid `window.history.back()` to #/load-data view?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the `$location.replace()` method to replace the last history entry.

[Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#replace-method) is the link to the documentation.

So when you are showing the spinner, you could switch to the actual view `show-info` with the following lines:

```
$location.path('/show-info/');
$location.replace();
```

Or shorter:

```
$location.path('/show-info/').replace();
```

Comment: This does not work when we use require.js for lazy loading... I have no clue why...