# How to remove last page with using $window.history.back()

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, history

In my code, logics are executed like belows.

1. Showing items list in main page.
2. Click one item and move to detail page.
3. I wanna change something, so click edit button and move to edit page.
4. Edit some and finish editing with click the confirm button.
5. When click the button, execute `$state.go('root.detail', {cat_id : $scope.cat_id}, {location: 'replace'});`.
6. Then move to detail page.

Through these, location history has successive detail page.

I know that we cannot handle history.

And I think using `$window.histroy.back();` is more appropriate instead of using

`$state.go('root.detail', {cat_id : $scope.cat_id}, {location: 'replace'});`

to remove history.

Anyone have idea to solve this?

.

.

.

I add my Paint files to make easy understanding what I want. :)

1.
[image]

2.
[image]

3.
[image]

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28743405/angularjs-how-to-remove-current-view-url-from-window-history If it helps.

Comment: @AvneshShakya I already see that post, but don't know how to adapt that in my code. I'm using ui-router, so `$state.go` is main function to move url.

Comment: @AvneshShakya and using replace executed same as `$state.go('root.detail', {cat_id : $scope.cat_id}, {location: 'replace'});`.

Comment: You can try `$state.transitionTo` for this. See this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/860 and see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105528/difference-between-state-transitionto-and-state-go-in-angular-ui-router

Comment: @AvneshShakya Is `$state.transitionTo` for using `$state.go` more specifically? I tried it also but, result is same.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved mine

```
    $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){  

         if(fromState.name == 'root.detail' && toState.name == "root.login"){
                 $location.path('/detailPagePath').replace();   
         };     
    });
```

Put this code in the detail page controller and add $location as a dependency....